# send a tweet from flash using as2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, twitter

I need to send a tweet from flash, so i've been looking for solution on the net, but everything i found is using as3. Since i don't know anything of as3, it becomes difficult to edit everything.

I wonder if it's possible.

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

posting a tweet requires the user being authenicated via OAuth. so assuming you have a user authenicated, you can just POST data to this URL:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

w/ post vars: `status`, `in_reply_to_status_id` (optional)

something like this:

```
var lv:LoadVars = new LoadVars()
lv.status = 'mystatus'
lv.in_reply_to_status_id = 'XXXXXX'
lv.onData = myDataHandlerFunction
lv.sendAndLoad( 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml', lv, 'POST');
```

The authentication process for OAuth is fairly complex. There are a few OAuth libs out there for flash, but all are AS3.

If you really are set on AS2, you can use a serverside OAuth library that you can interface your AS2 app with. Something like [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)

All signs point to learning AS3 if you plan on doing any real Flash/Twitter work, but you can get up and running with AS2 with a little more work.